# Can encryption cause problems?

Tags: php, encryption

I like to use AES-256-CBC for encrypting data in PHP:

```
$example = "abc";
$example = openssl_encrypt($example, "AES-256-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
```

A nice simple thing.

However, I'm worried that if I use encrypted as a string or similar in PHP, it will generate errors that break the code if it contains certain characters:

For example, the following characters in PHP:

> **"**

and

> **'**

Or if I use an encrypted string in a URL parameter, these character combinations:

> **?=**

and

> **&xy=**

Are both concerns justified? (I am unfortunately not a computer scientist)

Can the characters or combinations listed above occur at all in a string encoded in this way?

Or should I check encrypted strings for these characters BEFORE using them in PHP or in URL parameters and replace the characters listed above using preg_replace?

Thank you very much and greetings from Germany and from Google Translator :-)

Has anyone had any experience?

Comment: ik doubt it very much run it and try it, but of would occur someone has encountered alreeady

Comment: You could always convert the resulting encrypted string to some safe representation, such as a hex string, or base64 encode it, either of which will keep it to safe characters.

Answer (score 1):

For sure openssl_encrypt will not have problem to encrypt a string containing the following characters:

```
`
"
?=
&=
```

See the code below (which show that it can decrypt back the string thru openssl_decrypt faithfully):

```
<?php

$data = "SO's question and ?= " ;
$data .= ' SO "answer" and &= ' ;

$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
$secretKey = "ThisIsASecretKey123";
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($encryptionMethod));

$encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($data, $encryptionMethod, $secretKey, 0, $iv,);

$decryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
$decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, $decryptionMethod, $secretKey, 0, $iv);

echo $decryptedData;

?>
```

Result will be:

```
SO's question and ?=  SO "answer" and &=
```

See [demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/b80a0)